# Command \url{} not showing up in command palette Visual Studio Code

Tags: hyperref, urls, ide, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio Code, using the LaTeX Workshop extension, you can [surround selected text with a command or environment](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Snippets#surrounding-text). A hotkey brings up Command Palette and there you can choose the command. This works fine.

I now want to turn all the urls in my document into clickable links so I have added the hyperref package to my preamble. However even after reloading the document, the `\url{}` command does not show up in the Command Palette (neither does the `\href{}` command, by the way). I also can't seem to find a way to add new commands to it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally found the answer: in the settings, the box next to `latex-workshop.intellisense.package.enabled` must be ticked.